# Why am i not getting the print message?

Tags: python, input

in this little number guessing game, I have made in python, I intend on giving an output saying: Good job! You guessed correct. But whenever you guess the correct answer it doesn't show the output as I want it to. Am I making a silly error or is it something else?
following is the code:

```
 import random
range_1 = int(input("Enter your first range: "))
range_2 = int(input("Enter your second range: "))
x = random.randint(range_1, range_2)
print("Number chosen!")
guess = int(input(f"Guess the answer between {range_1} and {range_2}: "))

while guess != x:
    if guess > x:
        guess = int(input("Go lower: "))

    elif guess < x:
        guess = int(input("Go higher: "))
    
    else:
        print("Good job! You guessed correct!")
```

Comment: the answers will give you the solution to your problem. Just wanted to point out that if you introduce a `range_1` value larger than `range_2` your program will crash. you might want to handle that case. you can do something like `random.randint(min(range_1, range_2), max(range_1, range_2))` so it will handle it.

Comment: thankyou for the extra tip! will take this into consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can`t reach the else of the print.

The `while` loop check if guess is different than x, and the 2 if check if bigger or lower.

fix:

```
import random

range_1 = int(input("Enter your first range: "))
range_2 = int(input("Enter your second range: "))
x = random.randint(range_1, range_2)
print("Number chosen!")
guess = int(input(f"Guess the answer between {range_1} and {range_2}: "))

while guess != x:
    if guess > x:
        guess = int(input("Go lower: "))

    elif guess < x:
        guess = int(input("Go higher: "))

print("Good job! You guessed correct!")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the "you guessed correct" statement is in the while loop. Once `guess` has the correct value, the loop is exited and the print statement is never reached.

One fix is to put this print statement after the loop. Consider the following:

```
while guess != x:
    if guess > x:
        guess = int(input("Go lower: "))

    elif guess < x:
        guess = int(input("Go higher: "))

print("Good job! You guessed correct!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Fine job mate :)
Just put it after the loop, because when condition is met: `guess == x` it will not stay in the loop to get it in `elif`.

```
while guess != x:
    if guess > x:
        guess = int(input("Go lower: "))

    elif guess < x:
        guess = int(input("Go higher: "))

print("Good job! You guessed correct!")
```

If you want it inside the loop badly, then you might go with:

```
while guess != x:
    if guess > x:
        guess = int(input("Go lower: "))

    elif guess < x:
        guess = int(input("Go higher: "))

    if guess == x:
        print("Good job! You guessed correct!")
```